# How is creating an instance of a subclass extending an abstract parent class using a mix-up of both the class names error-free?

Tags: java, instantiation, abstract

I believe this question needs some illustration.

So, here is a sample code.

```
// Animal - abstract class (Parent class)
// Dog - inherited class (Sub class)

Animal puppy = new Dog(); // creating an instance.
```

So my question is, how is using both the class names when instantiating an object is right?
My pardon If this comes as a silly question. Can someone explain the breakdown of this weird instantiation?

Comment: `Dog` is a *subtype* of `Animal`, therefore every `Dog` is also an `Animal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Dog()` creates a new instance of Dog and returns a reference to that Dog

`Animal puppy` creates a variable (a named thing that can hold a reference to an object) that is capable of referring to any object that is an Animal

`=` initializes the variable on the left to the value on the right.  Since a Dog **is** an Animal, a reference to a Dog **is** a reference to an Animal, and therefore the initialization is legal.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed clarification and I would like to add something I found just recently that this is Polymorphism which is basically when a parent class reference is used to refer to a child class object.